# Frequency of $\exp(-iar^2)$ at $r_0$

Tags: exponential-function

I have an oscillating function
$$A(r)=A_0\exp\left(-i\frac{\lambda_0}{4\pi F}r^2\right)$$
This creates an oscillation with increasing frequency, depending on $r$. But how do I now get the oscillation frequency at a certain spot $r_0$? It would be easy if the equation depends on $r$ (then it would be $\frac{\lambda_0}{4\pi F}$), but not if it depends on $r^2$.

Comment: Did you miss an exponential right after $A_0$?

Comment: Yes, oops... Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the phase

$$
\phi(r) = \frac{\lambda_0}{4\pi F}r^2
$$

you could define the [instantaneous frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase) as

$$
k(r) = \frac{{\rm d}\phi}{{\rm d}r} = \frac{\lambda_0 r}{2\pi F}
$$